# iOS - Programatically load view on app didFinishingLaunching

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

This question is mostly about how I should structure my app. When the app loads the user can select from a list of videos to play, however the actual video player is on a different view controller. At the moment I am just keeping that view controller in memory so that the video can play continuously while the user is navigating throughout the app.

So the problems is that if the user selects a video before loading that movie view controller, nothing will happen of course.

How should I structure my app so that the video can play continuously whether or not the movie player view controller is held in memory? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do; but a default project created in XCode will "Programatically load view on app didFinishingLaunching" without any further coding needed.

Generally you should structure your app with an initial view or view controller (like a navigation controller); and start any visible actions in the "viewDidLoad" method of the target view.

In your case, I would recommend loading straight to the video controller first; and then programmatically segueing to the video selector view if no video is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I create a structure like this in my projects, I think you need to take a special look in `OverlayViewController`, check out a example:

```
MainViewController - As rootViewController
|- content (Any view controller to be presented, yes inside MainViewController)
|- OverlayViewController (a view controller over content )
```

This structure allows you to change contents without change entire hierarchy.

At `MainViewController` you will need a method to change current content to another, there is a simple example of how can you do that:

```
// PS I'm not sure if this will work in the first try, I wrote from my mind right now :)
func changeViewController (controller: UIViewController) {
  let from: UIViewController

  if childViewControllers.count > 0 {
    from = childViewControllers.first as! UIViewController
  }
  else {
    presentViewController(controller)
    return
  }

  let transitionContext = SomeViewControllerContextTransitioning (
    fromViewController: from,
    toViewController: controller
  )

  transitionContext.onAnimationComplete = { success in

    if !success {
      // TODO: Error fallback
    }
    else {
      from.view.removeFromSuperview()
      from.removeFromParentViewController()
      controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

  }

  from.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
  addChildViewController(controller)

  SomeAnimator().animateTransition(transitionContext)
}
```

And finally, in your `MainViewController` you can observe or control your video playback.

I hope this can help you.